# Run Spring Boot Application With Dev Configuration Or Test Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-profiles

I have some multi-environment configurations.

The `application.yml` is like

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @profileActive@
```

The `application-dev.yml` is like

```yaml
server:
  port: 8085

  spring:
    application:
      name: xxxx-info
    datasource:
      name: xxx-db
      type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
      url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.14:3306/xxx
      username: root
      password: *******
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      minIdle: 1
      maxActive: 8
      initialSize : 1
      testWhileIdle: true

  mybatis:
    typeAliasesPackage: com.xxx.commons.common.entity
    mapperLocations: classpath:mybatis/*.xml
```

And the `application-test.yml` is the same as `application-dev.yml`.

`Application.java` is like

```java
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@MapperScan("com.xxx.ggg.client.dao")
public class ClientInfoApplication {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientInfoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientInfoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then I run spring boot application in IntelliJ[image: spring run configuration]

**Here is the problem. Running spring boot application with application-test.yml is successful but not with application-dev.yml.**

The logs are like

```
2018-12-17 14:27:23.497 [main][INFO]com.xxx.ggg.client.ClientInfoApplication[597]: The following profiles are active: dev
2018-12-17 14:27:24.490 [main][INFO]org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol[180]: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018-12-17 14:27:24.499 [main][INFO]org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService[180]: Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-17 14:27:24.500 [main][INFO]org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine[180]: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-12-17 14:27:24.644 [localhost-startStop-1][INFO]org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/][180]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-17 14:27:24.956 [main][WARN]org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[551]: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInfoRunner': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tagService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tagInfoDao' defined in file [D:\projects\ggg\client-info\target\classes\com\xxx\ggg\client\dao\TagInfoDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "dev" are currently active).
2018-12-17 14:27:24.956 [main][INFO]org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService[180]: Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-12-17 14:27:24.981 [main][ERROR]org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter[42]: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "dev" are currently active).
```

Comment: Please Help me.Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use your build to produce multiple artifacts... That is what you are doing (judging from the `@profileActive@` in your `application.yml`).

Comment: can you add your class `DruidDataSource` Bean Creation Class Code to identify the problem..

Comment: @M.Deinum Then why it works for test.yml using my build??? You can see i add a active profile(test or dev) in IntelliJ to run.

Comment: Because you have some build that replaces the `@profileActive@` this doesn't work locally. Next to that it simply is bad to regenerate an artifact to promote it to the next stage. It basically means you are putting an untested artifact into the next stage and thus eventually in production.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you very much.Could you please tell me what is the best practice when using multi configurations ? I want to focus on my business but not modify configurations usually when in developing.

Comment: Run with the correct profile for the environment, don't rebuild the artifact for that.